# Can't scoll on algolia instantsearch UI Filters page (on mobile)

Tags: reactjs, algolia

https://github.com/ThePrimeDev/herfullpage

Here somehow if I'm on mobile, I have 2 issues:

1. I can't scroll in the filters menu on mobile
2. If I'm on a smaller viewport phone, the refinement lists just flow out of the screen, I can't set them to wrap into a single column (I searched algolia docs, but I didn't find anything)

Any ideas?

I tried searching the docs, and asking other people.